# single digit error using Hamming code

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I have a problem in part d

I still don't understand why an error of a single digit can not necessarily be decoded. I don't actually know why we need to consider the hamming distance of 2?
And for example, the original message is $\left ( 0,0,0,0,0,0 \right )$, and there is error in the first digit, so it is $\left ( 1,0,0,0,0,0 \right )$, then of course I can detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the distances along the number line.  You can get a code with distance $2$ by making the code words all the even numbers.  If you receive an odd number, you don't know whether to go up or down, but you will know it is wrong.  This is why a code with distance $2$ can detect but not correct single errors.

If the distance between legal words is $2$, then a word at distance $1$ from one code word could also be at a distance $1$ from another.  In that case you don't know how to resolve the error.  In your example, the data is $(0,0,0)$ which becomes a code word $(0,0,0,0,0,0)$.  If the error is in the third bit, the received message would be $(0,0,1,0,0,0)$, but a legal word is $(0,0,1,0,1,0)$, so you don't know which legal word to correct to.  If the sixth bit is defined as $m_1+m_3 \ldots$